# How do I avoid this back trace error after my program displays its output?

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, memory-leaks

This is a detailed program I am trying to implement:
A naturalist is off to explore the amazon jungle, and needs a computer program to record information about all the new species discovered. For each new species it is necessary to store the name (max 128 characters), size (a real number), and the type of animal. mammal, insect, bird, or fish).
Here is what a sample run should look like (with the keyboard input shown in italics) ...

```
> NewSpecies
Enter animal information ("exit" to exit)
What is the name : bloatfish
What is the size : 12.47
What is the type : fish
Enter animal information ("exit" to exit)
What is the name : stingybeasty
What is the size : 0.13
What is the type : insect
Enter animal information ("exit" to exit)
What is the name : toothfulsloth
What is the size : 33.33
What is the type : mammal
Enter animal information ("exit" to exit)
What is the name : exit

The following new species were found:
bloatfish            has size  12.47 and is a fish
stingybeasty         has size   0.13 and is a insect
toothfulsloth        has size  33.33 and is a mammal 
You must ...
Implement the program in C.
```

An array of structures must be used, so that each new species can be recorded in an element of the array.
The type of animal is represented as an enum type, indicating one of mammal, insect, bird, or fish.
It's not known in advance how many new species will be found, so the program must malloc for an initial array of size 1, and use the doubling realloc technique to get more memory as required. You must always check the return value from malloc, as done in the Malloc wrapper function (or just use Malloc :-).

My attempt:

```
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>

    #define MAX_CHAR 128
    #define LENGTH(A) (sizeof(A)/sizeof(A[0]))

    typedef char String[MAX_CHAR];
    typedef enum {mammal, insect, bird, fish, error} AnimalType;

    typedef struct{
      String name;
      double size;
      AnimalType type;
    } Animal;

    void * Malloc(size_t Size) {

        void * Memory;

        if ((Memory = malloc(Size)) == NULL) {
            perror("Cannot malloc");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        } else {
            return(Memory);
        }
    }

    AnimalType CheckAnimalType(String type) {
        if (!strcmp(type,"mammal")) {
            return (mammal);
        }
        if (!strcmp(type,"insect")) {
            return (insect);
        }
        if (!strcmp(type,"bird")) {
            return (bird);
        }
        if (!strcmp(type,"fish")) {
            return (fish);
        }
        return (error);
    }

    char *PrintAnimalType(AnimalType type){
      switch(type){
        case mammal: return "mammal"; break;
        case insect: return "insect"; break;
        case bird: return "bird"; break;
        case fish: return "fish"; break;
        case error: return "error";
      }
      return "error";

    }
    void printData(Animal *animal, int size) {
        printf("The following species were found:\n");
        for(int i = 0; i < size-1; i++)
            printf("%s has size %.2lf and is a %s\n", animal[i].name, animal[i].size, PrintAnimalType(animal[i].type));
    }

    void MainMenu(Animal *animal, int *size){
      for(;;){
        Animal newAnimal;
        String animalName;
        double animalSize;
        String animalType;

        printf("Enter animal information (\"exit\" to exit)\n");

        printf("What is the name : ");
        scanf("%s", animalName);
        if(!strcmp(animalName, "exit")) break;
        strcpy(newAnimal.name, animalName);

        printf("What is the size : ");
        scanf("%lf", &animalSize);
        if(newAnimal.size == 0) break;
        newAnimal.size = animalSize;

        printf("What is the type : ");
        scanf("%s", animalType);
        newAnimal.type = CheckAnimalType(animalType);

        if((animal = realloc(animal, sizeof(newAnimal)*((*size)+1))) == NULL) {
                printf("MEMORY ERROR: problem reallocating array\n");
                return;
            }
         animal[(*size)-1] = newAnimal;
            (*size)++;
      }
      printData(animal, *size);
    }



    int main(void) {
      int size = 1;
      Animal *animal = Malloc(sizeof(Animal));
      MainMenu(animal, &size);
      free(animal);
      return 0;
    }
```

I am attempting to implement the above in C but I get this error directly after execution:

Link to error: https://pastebin.com/Wcu0wtet

[image]

Comment: The error dump should be included as text, not an image.

Comment: And please show the program log before that point. That is, what did you input and how far did the program get?

Comment: Thanks: https://pastebin.com/Wcu0wtet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `MainMenu` you call `realloc` on `animal`.  This may resize the existing buffer, but usually allocates a new on, changing the value of the pointer.  The new pointer is stored in the local `animal` variable, and not the variable in `main`.

When you return to `main`, you call `free(animal)`, which will attempt to free the original animal buffer that has already been freed by the call to `realloc`.

You'll want to pass the modified buffer pointer back to the caller, either as a return value, or by passing a pointer to the original variable (`Animal **`).

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I spent over 6 hours on this. I removed free(animals) to MainMenu and it fixed everything